# Dmesg shows no timestamp

Tags: startup, logs, system-information

The sudo dmesg command works fine, but shows no timestamp. Is there any way to get it to show the timestamps as well?

Comment: The log info does show with timestamp in Console.app and system.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not by using `dmesg` which is a very simple command. But you can use

```
sudo fgrep "kernel[0]" /var/log/system.log
```

instead to get the same messages from the system log file, including a time stamp.

Comment: command returns nothing in MacOS Catalina v10.15.6

Comment: @rmsys The logging system has changed significantly since 2013, a lot of log data is accessible via the `log` command.

Comment: To get the logs of past two hours (2h) for instance: `log show --debug --last 2h --color always --style default --pager`
Opens the logs in `less` in a paginated format. Can change `--pager` to `--no-pager` to not use `less`.